# How to get last running transaction Id in magento

Tags: magento

How can I get the last running transaction Id ? (eg: 10000001)
I've tried numerous ways, with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was suddenly enlightened when I looked at the problem again at home. Why not get the last order increment id from the sales/order collection?

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->setOrder('increment_id','DESC')
        ->setPageSize(1)
        ->setCurPage(1);

echo $orders->getFirstItem()->getIncrementId();
```

Tested and working on Magento 1.3.2.3

Comment: Amazing! I tried doing that, but was not successful. what does the setpageset do ?

Comment: setPageSize and setCurPage limit the number of items returned by the collection. In this case we just need one item - the one with the highest increment_id, so I've changed the page size to one item and requested only the first page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
```

Comment: This works only if a valid checkout session is in progress (I hope I'm correct by saying this) - or in other words, it works when I invoke it from the checkout event.

I wasn't clear on this in my question above, but I'm trying to get it without such a session in progress.

Comment: In this case you might try to get it directly from the db. I will post an example sql statement when I get back from work. In the meantime, could you state which magento version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbc_collect_order = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');   
$items_collect_order = $dbc_collect_order->fetchAll("SELECT `increment_id` FROM `sales_flat_order` ORDER BY `entity_id` DESC LIMIT 1");
echo $last_main_order_id = $items_collect_order['0']['increment_id'];
```

Comment: it's not "Magento way" solution. Please refer to other posted anwsers.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there is a more simpler answer to silvo's:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
echo $orders->getLastItem()->getIncrementId();
```