# How to get latest order No. from onepageController.php in checkout module in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

How to get latest order No. from onepageController.php in checkout module in Magento? Or how can I get last booked order No. on onepageController.php file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195743/get-order-increment-id-in-magento / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698395/how-to-get-last-running-transaction-id-in-magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

```
            $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getEntityType('order')
            ->fetchNewIncrementId($this->getStoreId());
```

magento have different incrementId per store.

Comment: "(...)magento have different incrementId per store.(...)" - not quite true as they can have same increment_id for each store.

Check `increment_per_store` in `eav_entity_type`